Angular Signals inside effect()
In a component, I am accessing item_id as input parameter.
Where can I call toSignal() or .subscribe() to service method, if it is not allowed inside constructor / ngOnInit() effect()?
 item_id = input<string>();

 constructor() {
    effect(() => {
      const itemId = this.item_id();
      if (itemId !== undefined) {
        this.itemSvc.setItemId(itemId); // setup the observable service with itemId
        this.itemSvc.itemDetails().subscribe({ }) // subscribe to get the data about particular itemId
        });
      }
    });

P.S. computed() is also not working. Do you know the reason why ?
ItemData$ = computed(() => {
const itemId = this.item_id(); 
if (itemId !== undefined) { 
this.itemSvc.setItemId(itemId); 
return this.itemSvc.itemDetails(); 
} 
return signal<Item | null>(null); }); 


You can just use toObservable for this. To Convert to observable then use switchMap to switch to the API observable you need, this will react when the signal changes.
  item_id = input<string>();
  itemDetails = toObservable(this.item_id).pipe(
    switchMap((itemId: string) => {
      if (itemId !== undefined) {
        this.itemSvc.setItemId(itemId); // setup the observable service with itemId
        return this.itemSvc.itemDetails();
      }
      return of([]);
    })
  );


I am trying to read it as computed():
ItemData$ = computed(() => {
const itemId = this.item_id();
if (itemId !== undefined) {
this.itemSvc.setItemId(itemId);
return toSignal(this.itemSvc.itemDetails());
}
return signal<Item | null>(null);
});
but in the template somehow it is missing: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Signal<Item | null>'.ngtsc(2339)

@NevyanDimitrovNeykov the code is different, we do not need toSignal

yes even without the toSignal() in the template the signal data is not recognized to have properties.

@NevyanDimitrovNeykov please replicate the issue in this stackblitz will check it for you!

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-98k78k

@NevyanDimitrovNeykov sorry for late reply. Here is it stackblitz

thanks, I was looking for the computed() solution, but apparently with toObservable() is the way to listen to item_id() signal changes.
